# Is it possible to put the alias before the columnName as in tsql?

Tags: presto

This syntax doesn't work but is there anything like it? There are a lot of really long column names and I like being able to scan down the line and see exactly what's what.

```
select 
    price = superLongConvolutedNameforPrice,
    weight = packageWeightInOunces
from ...
```

If there's nothing like this I understand, but I prefer putting the alias first for readability reasons.

Aligned aliases is probably what I'll go with but I figured I'd throw this out in case there was another way to make readable aliases for a long list of really long column names.

Comment: It might be better readable by you, but as it is not default behaviour, it is less readable for other users. Also, when you get yourself used to this, other peoples code which is confirm normal uses, feels weird to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no currently way to inverse select expression and the alias in Presto.